# Quadratic form inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, self-learning

I'm working on a problem, and to finish it I need to show that

$$\mu^T (I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)\mu \geq 0$$

But I'm stuck at showing this.

My first thought was to write this as trace

$$tr(\mu^T\mu) \geq tr(\mu^T X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \mu)$$

and try to use the idempotence of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and the fact its rank is $r(X) \leq n$. However I don't really see how that helps here.

Alternatively, I thought I could use the formula for the expected value of a quadratic form, which involves terms like the traces involved. But again, not much luck.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is not only idempotent but also symmetric, hence an orthogonal projection. The same is true for $I -X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$: it is symmetric and idempotent. Then
$$
\mu^T( I -X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)\mu = \mu^T( I -X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^2\mu
= \|( I -X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)\mu\|^2 \ge0.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to think of the problem in terms of geometry and projections even though that’s the main underlying theme